# Why can't I download a whole image file with urllib2.urlopen()

Tags: python, image, download

When I run the following code, it only seems to be downloading the first little bit of the file and then exiting. Occassionally, I will get a 10054 error, but usually it just exits without getting the whole file. My internet connection is crappy wireless, and I often get broken downloads on larger files in firefox, but my browser has no problem getting a 200k image file. I'm new to python, and programming in general, so I'm wondering what nuance I'm missing.

```
import urllib2
xkcdpic=urllib2.urlopen("http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/literally.png")
xkcdpicfile=open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\John Gann\\Desktop\\xkcd.png","w")
while 1:
    chunk=xkcdpic.read(4028)
    if chunk:
        print chunk
        xkcdpicfile.write(chunk)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To write a binary file on Windows you need to explicitly *open* it as binary, i.e.:

```
xkcdpicfile=open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\John Gann\\Desktop\\xkcd.png",
                 "wb")
```

note the extra `b` in the options: `"wb"`, **not** just `"w"`!

I would also recommend losing the `print chunk` which may send arbitrary binary sequences to the console and possibly caused undesired side effects.  If you're keen to see the hex bytes whizz by meaninglessly, maybe `print repr(chunk)`, if you insist.  But I'd find something more meaningful to show, e.g. `len(chunk)` and maybe the total number of bytes so far.

Comment: Thanks. Works a treat now. I'd never noticed a difference between "w" and "wb" working with files locally, even with images.